# How to convert a CURL request to Ruby Gem HTTPClient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, rest-client

I am trying to convert this CURL request:

```
curl \
  -F 'slideshow_spec={ 
    "images_urls": [ 
      "<IMAGE_URL_1>", 
      "<IMAGE_URL_2>", 
      "<IMAGE_URL_3>" 
    ], 
    "duration_ms": 2000, 
    "transition_ms": 200 
  }' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://google.com
```

To a HTTPClient request but all my attempts results in 400 Bad Request. Here's what I've tried:

```
  payload = {
        "images_urls": [
          "https://cdn-m2.esoftsystems.com/10100028/TAASTRUP%40DANBOLIG.DK/10106239925/160596797/BEST_FIT/1542/1024/IMG_5511.jpg",
          "https://cdn-m2.esoftsystems.com/10100028/TAASTRUP%40DANBOLIG.DK/10106239925/160596797/BEST_FIT/1542/1024/IMG_5511.jpg",
          "https://cdn-m2.esoftsystems.com/10100028/TAASTRUP%40DANBOLIG.DK/10106239925/160596797/BEST_FIT/1542/1024/IMG_5511.jpg"
        ],
        "duration_ms": 2000,
        "transition_ms": 200
      }

  response = RestClient.post url, {slideshow_spec: payload.to_json, multipart: true, access_token: access_token}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your requests are not equivalent. I guess you are mixing `JSON`, `Multipart` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` formats here.

RestClient supports all three formats (examples taken from https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/README.md)

```
# POST JSON
RestClient.post "http://example.com/resource", {'x' => 1}.to_json, {content_type: :json, accept: :json}

# POST Multipart
# Usually not needed if you don't want to upload a file
RestClient.post '/data', {:foo => 'bar', :multipart => true}

# POST x-www-form-urlencoded
RestClient.post('https://httpbin.org/post', {foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux'})
```

Looks like your curl sample uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, while your Ruby sample uses `multipart/form-data`.

For some background information, check

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST
- https://dev.to/sidthesloth92/understanding-html-form-encoding-url-encoded-and-multipart-forms-3lpa

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [curlify](https://rubygems.org/gems/curlify) gem. The curlify gem converts HTTP requests to curl command.